# How to post to a newly created page?

Tags: php, database, post

I am fairly new to PHP. I've been studying it for a few weeks now and still getting the hang of it. I figured out how to make a form, submit it and put it in the database.

But I can not figure out how  I can get that newly created data and create a new page with the data being on that page. (I know I'd have to attach includes for the static content)

For example, reddit. You create a new topic, post a link and some text then submit it, becomes available on the homepage, and you can click on it to view the post.

I have an idea of a project that I want to do, and it will do something similar to that, but I just can't figure out how to crate a new page.

Could maybe someone explain, link me to a tutorial, PHP reference to anything that can help me?

Comment: Can you post your code that you have so far?

Comment: ^ I haven't tried anything really, I don't know where to start.

Comment: But you have your code to insert data into the database?

Answer (score 0):

You would use `int mysql_insert_id ([ resource $link_identifier ] )`

the `mysql_insert_id` retrieves the id of the last inserted row assuming that you have an auto-incrementing id field in your database.

and use that in a select statement. More info below.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

cited from above link:

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('mydb');

mysql_query("INSERT INTO mytable (product) values ('kossu')");
printf("Last inserted record has id %d\n", mysql_insert_id());
?>
```

which means you could use something like:

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('mydb');

mysql_query("INSERT INTO mytable (product) values ('kossu')");
$id = mysql_insert_id();
mysql_query("SELECT " . $id . " FROM mytable");
?>
```

Comment: All that you are doing, after you run your query, is run the function `mysql_insert_id());` which retrieves the last inserted row. From that you can retrieve the data using a `SELECT` statement using the `id` you have just found.

Comment: So what would it look like after they submit there information?

Comment: What is your code that you are using to submit information into the database?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to create a new page, then use file_put_contents and other functions of the sort. But if you want to do it the way reddit, YouTube, and others do, you will have to create a MySQL database. You insert data into the database, and when you want to get it back, you use apache's `mod_rewrite` to make it look like a file. That's how the big sites do it.

Comment: Trippy has mentioned that the data is in the database so all that is needed is to retrieve the last row. Your method is a lot more cumbersome as Trippy already has the database in place.

Comment: Then ignore the part about creating a database. But `mod_rewrite` is an important part to this process. All you did was give him half of the equation.